# CollectionView Cell Resizing from Internal AutoLayout

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, autolayout

I'm adding shadow to a cell, however when I start using autolayout to set objects within the cell it negatively effects the shape of the cell.  I've tried various stages of views/nib loading, but can't seem to get the combo right.  What can I do to allow for using autolayout within the cell?

Desired (no autolayout):

[image]

Result (after setting the label to "equal width" and distance from bottom):

[image]

From the viewcontroller:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
      let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "PlacesCell", for: indexPath) as! PlacesCollectionViewCell

    let shadowPath2 = UIBezierPath(rect: cell.bounds)
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    cell.layer.masksToBounds = false
    cell.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: CGFloat(2.0), height: CGFloat(6.0))
    cell.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
    cell.layer.shadowPath = shadowPath2.cgPath

    cell.name.text = someObjects[indexPath.row].name

    return cell
}

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let noOfCellsInRow = 2
    let flowLayout = collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
    let totalSpace = flowLayout.sectionInset.left
        + flowLayout.sectionInset.right
        + (flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing * CGFloat(noOfCellsInRow - 1))
    let size = Int((collectionView.bounds.width - totalSpace) / CGFloat(noOfCellsInRow))
    return CGSize(width: size, height: size)
}

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

     if let cell = sender as? UICollectionViewCell,
        let indexPath = self.placesCollectionView.indexPath(for: cell) {
        let vc = segue.destination as! PeopleViewController
        vc.placeForReference = someObjects[indexPath.row] //Pass object
    }
}
```

The cell's class only inherits from UICollectionViewCell.

Comment: First, did you check if sizeForItem is getting called? If so, then try playing with the label's content hugging priority. Set it to a lower value and see what happens.

Comment: sizeForItem is getting called, and content hugging doesnt seem to impact much. The strange this is that it only happens with UILabels, and only on this ViewController. Could the fact that it's created from a segue in another VC matter?

Comment: I updated the code to add the segue.

Comment: The segue should not affect anything related to your issue. I don't know if you have other choice than to drop the equal widths constraint and put the center the label if this is what you want to achieve

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  I was really hoping to be able to overlay a semi-opaque "lower-thirds" over an image in the cell; not sure how to do that without telling the label to go full width....

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out; in the collectionview's settings I needed to change the "Estimated Size" to "None".

[image]